# Render data from Firebase Firestore in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so I'm trying to render some data from a Firebase Firestore DB in my app, I followed a certain tutorial that got me up and running but now that I'm trying to figure out how to pull data from my own DB, that is something else.

Here is my code block that I think is what will listen to data from firestore based on a control number inputted by a user, for now the control number is hard coded before i will figure out how to get the value from a form.

```
//Code to Query data from Database
function SingleQuery() {
  const [drivers, setDrivers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("drivers")
      .where("controlNumber", "==", "202003010850-014746") //get data according to control number
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const newDriver = snapshot.docs.map((doc) =>
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data()
        )
        });
        setDrivers(newDriver);
      });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return drivers;
}
```

After that, its expected to render the data here:

```
<div id="results-list">
  {drivers.map((driver) =>
    <ol key={driver.id}>
     <li>{driver.controlNumber}</li>
    </ol>
)}
</div>
```

Right now I'm getting a mixed of parsing errors and unexpected tokens.

---

Hello everyone, this is an update. I now have everything up and running but I'm wondering if any of you can help me with querying data from Firestore according to the control number entered by a user.

```
<div className="violationQuery">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <h4>Enter Control Number</h4>
      <div className="searchBar" class="input-group-sm">
        <form>
          <input
           type="text"
           className="form-control"
           aria-label="Small"
           aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
           placeholder="Control Number"
           id="controlNum"
          />
           <br />
         <input className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
</div>
```

I need to get the value of inputted and place it in the where() method in the SingleQuery Hook above.

Comment: Can you please share those parsing errors? And also share the code of how you are using SingleQuery hook.

Comment: hi, sure.

Here's the code for SingleQuery:

`
export const violationQuery = () => {
  const drivers = SingleQuery();
`

And below that code is a return() containing the code for the search bar and the code for rendering the data

Here's a parsing error too:
_Parsing error: The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis_

its pointed to the colon in "id:" in SingleQuery

Comment: Instead of putting that info in a comment, add it to your question by clicking the little `edit` link under it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen my bad. its my first time asking here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your map method, Syntax is not correct. I think you are trying to create an Object and return it.

```js
//Code to Query data from Database
function SingleQuery() {
  const [drivers, setDrivers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("drivers")
      .where("controlNumber", "==", "202003010850-014746") //get data according to control number
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const newDriver = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {  
          return {   // returns a new Object
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data()
          };
        });
        setDrivers(newDriver);
      });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return drivers;
}
```

Comment: you may be able to help with my other question :(

Comment: have added my answer to your question